# Typescript Object is possible undefined, even with checker

Tags: typescript

I have an object which contains objects, something of this type:

```
myObject = {
a: {
id: 1
},
b: {
id: 2
}
```

These properties are being added dynamically.
I would like to change a property (id) to one of the properties on the object:

```
  if (this.myObject[prop] !== undefined) {
    this.myObject[prop].id= 4;
  }
```

Even with the guard, I get the error `Object is possibly undefined`

I can also verify that prop is defined

```
  if (props && this.myObject[prop] !== undefined) {
    this.myObject[prop].id= 4;
  }
```

And still receiving the same error.
It only works when I hard code the prop name (and verifying it with a guard):

```
  if (this.myObject.a !== undefined) {
    this.myObject.a.id= 4;
  }
```

How can I safely access a property on `myObject` and change a property inside it?

Comment: Have you tried storing `this.myObject[prop]` in a const first?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted, as-is, into a standalone IDE?  That will help people get started on solving the problem instead of spending any time re-creating it (or worse, making suggestions without being able to test them first).  If you do decide to [edit] to include such an example and want me to take another look, please comment and mention @jcalz so I will be notified.  Good luck!

Comment: Hey @jcalz thank you so much for wanting to help, I tried to recreate it with minimal code and no luck so far, I will try to further investigate it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
interface myObjectInterface {
    [key: string]: {
       id: number
    };
}

let myObject : myObjectInterface;

if (this.myObject && this.myObject[prop] && this.myObject[prop].id) {
    myObject[prop].id = 4;
}
```

Comment: Tnx that doesn't work, and even shows the error on this.myObject[prop].id inside the parenthesis